# Как изменить высоту ячейки после загрузки изображения

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Всем доброго времени суток
Проблема такая
Хочу чтобы изображения имеющие разный размер, изменяли свою высоту в зависимости от ширины устройства
Имеется `tableview` с новостями, типа в вк
Для отображения изображений из url я использую `kingfisher`
Вот код:

```
cell.image_of_new.kf.indicatorType = .activity
        cell.image_of_new.kf.setImage(
            with: url,
            placeholder: UIImage(named: "placeholderImage"),
            options: [
                .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                .transition(.fade(1)),
                .cacheOriginalImage
            ])
        {
            result in
                            let newHeight = (self.tableview.frame.width * CGFloat(result.value?.image.size.height ?? 100)) / CGFloat(result.value?.image.size.width ?? 100)
                            cell.image_height.constant = newHeight

        }
```

Как видите после `result in` я вычисляю высоту, затем меняю высоту изображения на новую `cell.image_height.constant = newHeight`
Как обновить ячейку после того как высота изображения поменялась
Я пробовал разные варианты, но это не подходит, ячейки скачут, или уходят в бесконечный цикл и таблица стоит:

```
cell.setNeedsLayout()
cell.layoutIfNeeded()  
------------------------
self.tableView.beginUpdates();
self.tableView.endUpdates();
------------------------
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
------------------------
DispatchQueue.main.async {
let newHeight = (self.tableview.frame.width * CGFloat(result.value?.image.size.height ?? 100)) / CGFloat(result.value?.image.size.width ?? 100)
                        cell.image_height.constant = newHeight
}
-------------------------
```

Как правильно решить эту проблему, кто сталкивался с этим?
  Как правильно сделать такую новостную ленту?

Comment: Вам надо уходить от преобразований параметров напрямую в сторону constraints. Вы сейчас вычисляете значения высоты вручную, а констрейнты позволят вам автоматизировать это.

Comment: @Olter, вы не подскажете как бы я мог это сделать?

Comment: И еще один момент. По вашему вопросу не понятно, надо ли вам обновлять ячейки в реальном времени. Т.к сначала вы пишите, что: "изменяли свою высоту в зависимости от ширины устройства" - по идее вам достаточно один раз посчитать нужный размер во ViewDidLoad или viewWillAppear. А потом уже "Как обновить ячейку после того как высота изображения поменялась?" В каком случае у вас может меняться высота изображения? В общем, распишите задачу подробнее. У вас может в разных ячейках быть изображения с разными размерами?

Comment: Да, у меня в каждой ячейке могут быть изображения разного размера, обновлять в реальном времени не нужно. Нужно один раз посчитать размер и все

Comment: Изображения вы грузите асинхронно? Т.е вам известен их размер до загрузки страницы или вы сначала рисуете таблицу, потом грузите изображения и перерисовываете таблицу? Добавьте код методов heightForRowAtIndexPath и cellForRowAtIndexPath, тогда станет понятно.

Comment: Мне не известен размер изображений до загрузки, сначала рисуется и потом в нее загружается изображение

Answer (score 0):

После долгого поиска я нашел решение этой проблемы в этом ответе
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48937190/10718471
Код:

```
class ScaledHeightImageView: UIImageView {

override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

    if let myImage = self.image {
        let myImageWidth = myImage.size.width
        let myImageHeight = myImage.size.height
        let myViewWidth = self.frame.size.width

        let ratio = myViewWidth/myImageWidth
        let scaledHeight = myImageHeight * ratio

        return CGSize(width: myViewWidth, height: scaledHeight)
    }

    return CGSize(width: -1.0, height: -1.0)
}}
```